# To Manage Schedule in PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, logic

I am having table like below

[image]

So there are priority and sqft, i want to start manufacturing schedule (from current date) that every day 1700 SQFT will be processed, like below image

[image]

but as you can see its not working

I have tried below code

```
foreach($priorityArraySum as $key=>$val)
{
                    
   $totalDays=ceil($val/1700);
   $cutSQFT=$val;
                    
    for($j=1;$j<=$totalDays;$j++)
    {
        if($cutSQFT>1700)
        {
          echo '1700';
         $cutDate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($cutDate. ' + 1 days'));
         $cutSQFT=$cutSQFT-1700;
        }
        else
        {
          echo $cutSQFT;
          $cutSQFT=$cutSQFT-$cutSQFT;
        }
    }
```

}

@Nigel, to Make this dynamic, I have changed code to below, but its not working.

```
$pln_qry=mysql_query("select * from tbl_mfg_schedule where ms_date='".$today."'") or die(mysql_error());
                $pln_data=mysql_fetch_array($pln_qry);
                
                $max = $pln_data['ms_po_sqft'];
                $dailyLeft = $max;
                $current = reset($priorityArraySum);
                $output = [];
                //$day = date('Y-m-d');
                $day = date('Y-m-d');
                while (true)    {
                    
                    $pln_qry=mysql_query("select * from tbl_mfg_schedule where ms_date='".$today."'") or die(mysql_error());
                    $pln_data=mysql_fetch_array($pln_qry);
                
                    $max = $pln_data['ms_po_sqft'];
                
                        if ( $current >= $dailyLeft )   {
                            //$day=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day. ' + 1 days'));
                            $output[] = ["priority" => key($priorityArraySum),
                                    "amount" => $dailyLeft,
                                    "day" => $day
                            ];
                            $day=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day. ' + 1 days'));
                            $current -= $dailyLeft;
                            $dailyLeft = $max;
                        }
                        else    {
                            $output[] = ["priority" => key($priorityArraySum),
                                    "amount" => $current,
                                    "day" => $day
                            ];
                            $dailyLeft -= $current;
                            if ( ($current = next($priorityArraySum)) === false )   {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    
                    
                }
```

Comment: Please paste the data as array values, not as pictures.

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: @Epodax logic for for loop is not working, as you can see it is working perfect till priority 2, for priority 3 it is taking only 282.59 sqft

Comment: Your code does _not_ produce the result you say it does, with the given input data. Give us a _proper_ [mre], including the actual data in code form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code uses a `while()` loop to create an output array of the days work.  It uses `$current` to keep track of each item and how much is left to allocate.  It also uses `$dailyLeft` to keep track of how much capacity is left on a particular day.  It checks the two and if the current is less than the daily capacity left, it allocates a full day to that item and resets the daily capacity.  If there is extra capacity for that day it allocates this item to the day and gets the next item.

The day is only incremented (using `$day++`) when the capacity for that day is filled...

```
$max = 1700;
$dailyLeft = $max;
$current = reset($priorityArraySum);
$output = [];
$day = 1;
while (true)    {
    // echo $current."/".$dailyLeft."=".$day.PHP_EOL;
    if ( $current >= $dailyLeft )   {
        $output[] = ["priority" => key($priorityArraySum),
                "amount" => $dailyLeft,
                "day" => $day++
        ];
        $current -= $dailyLeft;
        $dailyLeft = $max;
    }
    else    {
        $output[] = ["priority" => key($priorityArraySum),
                "amount" => $current,
                "day" => $day
        ];
        $dailyLeft -= $current;
        if ( ($current = next($priorityArraySum)) === false )   {
            break;
        }
    }
}
print_r($output);
```

Comment: What if I want to make daily capacity variable? like for 3 days it will be 1700 for weekend it will be 0 for some other days it will be 2000. (I will prepare table for capacity of entire month and will store it)

Comment: If you want to make the capacity variable, then I would suggest posting a new question - along with your attempts at getting that working.

Comment: ok, @Nigel will surely try my best, and if not succeed then will post new question. Thank you for your time

Comment: I have tried to alter the code to make it dynamic (see the original question, I have added altered code below in question) but its not working, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: also, made separate question at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63297519/convert-static-manufacturing-schedule-to-dynamic